# Remote db connection limits and MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have an app using a remote MySQL service and has `max_user_connections` set on the plans. For my pricing level, it's 30 connections. My app functions fine; all operations work.

However, while MySQL Workbench is open (for manual db imports) if I attempt to reboot my remote app I get an error:

```
[2022-02-04T22:24:05.313Z] error Error: ER_USER_LIMIT_REACHED: User '************' has exceeded the 'max_user_connections' resource (current value: 30)
```

Upon closing MYSQL Workbench, my remote app reboots fine.

My app has max connections set to 30, although just to be safe I made it 29 in an attempt to reserve 1 connection for MWB.

Do I need to reserve even more for MWB? How many connections would it need? Can I limit MWB on my local machine (Ubuntu) so it uses less (how about just one?) connections?

To avoid this in the future, what would be best? I suppose shut my app down for maintenance at 3am and run a DB job then.

Answer (score 0):

`max_connections` limits the number of simultaneous connections.

`max_user_connections` limits the number of simultaneous connections *from any one user*.

A single program, including a single instance of Workbench, should (normally) make only one connection.

Some novice programmers make a connection *inside* a subroutine and fail to `disconnect`.  What they *should* do is have a single connection for all database activity in the program.

"Reserving 1 for MWB" -- Let me ramble on for a moment before addressing this.

"Applications" and "users" should each have their own login.  30 users *should* be using more than a single login.  Otherwise, there is no hope of tracking them.

No "user" and no "application" should connect as the `SUPER` user (typically called 'root' or 'admin') *except* when doing admin stuff.

Your use of Workbench may qualify for "admin stuff", so you could be justified in connecting as 'root'.

MySQL reserves 1 connection (of the `max_connections`) for 'root'.  Actually, if `max_connections` is 100, and you connect as root, then you can see 101 connections in the extreme case.

There is only 1 'free pass', so don't load up MWB twice if all the 'users' are 'root', too.

**Summary**

Configure Workbench to log in as user 'root; give everyone else a non-super login.

Comment: (@MarsAndBack: If this analysis does not answer the question, then please provide more specifics about what is running, and how they are logged in.)